# How do I know if user's message is a reply?

Tags: python, telebot

I am using telebot for Python.

Is there any way I get to know if the message is a reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using this library: https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

If you have a [`Message`](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.Message) object `r`, you can check its `reply_to_message` attribute:

- If `reply_to_message` is another `Message` instance `m`, `r` is a reply to `m`.
- If `reply_to_message` is `None`, `r` is not a reply.

If you have a different library, it should work similarly, as it corresponds directly to the [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message).